# Configuring SSL in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, servlets

I am trying to create an example that uses HTTPS. I was successful in configuring SSL in Tomcat and also managed to create an example that used HTTPS. But when I run the example in Eclipse, I get a Page Cannot Be Displayed error message every time. I am sure that the code is working fine as I successfully ran it outside eclipse. 
Is there any special method to configure SSL in Eclipse? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to configure the server.xml created by eclipse. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951890/eclipse-wtp-how-do-i-enable-ssl-on-tomcat) for details

2) Since you already configured the tomcat outside eclipse, you may also want to checkout the [Sysdeo plugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html). You can point this plugin to the already configured tomcat(that resides outside eclipse). It lets you stop, start, restart tomcat while staying within eclipse. Also lets you run in debug mode.