# Tomcat server in eclipse does not support TSL/SSL

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ssl

I am trying to get self signed certificate for my website. I created a certificate using "Keytool" and then made following changes in conf/server.xml

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            redirectPort="8443" />

        <Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"
            keystoreFile="c:\tomcat\keystore\.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
            maxThreads="150" port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https"
            secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

When i run the tomcat server externally and type the URL https://"localhost":8443 (No quotes around localhost) it works but when i run the tomcat server in Eclipse i get 404 error. 
Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

I referred to the below sites for help.

http://technology-for-human.blogspot.com/2011/08/ssl-in-tomcat-under-eclipse-part-1-self.html

[Eclipse WTP: How do I enable SSL on Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951890/eclipse-wtp-how-do-i-enable-ssl-on-tomcat)

Comment: Why do you want to run https on a debugging server?

Comment: The https should run on any server rite?

Comment: Should and could yes, but as somebody myself who develops web services, I never even attempt to configure https on my debugging server, it adds no value. Unless you have a specific scenario that requires https

Comment: It is not working for me now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please remove the tomcat server from server tab in eclipse and then add again by specifically specifying the path of the server.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html
the *sslProtocol* property should be one of the followings: SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, all.
Try putting "TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2".

Be sure there's no exceptions regarding the keystore's path or password.

And last but not least, remove the *redirectPort* property from others Connectors.