# Apache Tomcat SSL Http11AprProtocol Connector

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, apr

I am working on Link-OS web-service with self-signed CA.

I followed [this](https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/How-to-Create-Self-Signed-Server-and-Device-Certificates-for-Weblink-Websockets-Connections?language=en_US) to create a self-signed CA

I deployed the printer server by following these instructions
https://github.com/ZebraDevs/LinkOS-Webservices-Samples

Whenever I add this part to **server.xml**, no page will work including **localhost:8080** although the server is running without showing or throwing errors or exceptions.

```
<Connector 
     protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
     SSLEnabled="true" SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"  
     maxThreads="200" port="8443" SSLVerifyClient="optional"
     scheme="https" secure="true"
     SSLCertificateFile="C:\cert\SERVER.crt" 
     SSLCertificateKeyFile="C:\cert\SERVER.key" 
     />
```

what could go wrong with these steps? I have followed them step by step

I am using:

- Java 8
- Tomcat 7
- APR 1.7

following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951890/eclipse-wtp-how-do-i-enable-ssl-on-tomcat) will make the server works fine, but it won't work with the printers, so it is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You used an [APR Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File) here. (`protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"`)

APR implementation needs Apache Portable Runtime (APR) and Tomcat Native library.

You can install them with these commands:

```
apt install libtcnative-1
apt install libapr1-dev libssl-dev
```

or if either package is not found, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41291170/5631676).

I think you should implement cert-sign certification without APR, because an APR connector needs extra libraries. İf you want, try [these instructions](https://linuxhint.com/tomcat_install_ssl_certificate).

Comment: Because APR connector needs extra libraries. So  implementation is a little difficult.

Comment: thank you for your answer, not sure if it is what I am looking for, but can you tell me how should be the structure of the Tomcat's connector using the generated files by following these instructions? https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/How-to-Create-Self-Signed-Server-and-Device-Certificates-for-Weblink-Websockets-Connections?language=en_US

Comment: you sould add SSLCertificateChainFile="/opt/tomcat/ssl/bundle.ca-bundle". for bundle: https://support.globalsign.com/ca-certificates/root-certificates/root-intermediate-certificate-bundles