# Enable ssl on tomcat service

Tags: ssl, tomcat, server.xml

I have wanted to make my tomcat service connection as secure. So I’ve generated the CSR and got a sign-in from my originations. While generating the CSR, I have for .CSR and Key file. When I do a sign in I have received the below certificates.

ServerCertifictae.crt and ChainBundle2.crt (combination of Root and inetemident.crt files)

To enable the SSL, I have configured the below setting in the server.xml file which will be available in the tomcat config folder. After the config change, I have done the necessary service restarts. But still, tomcat not taking the SSL certificate and could see non-secure connections.

Kindly help me out. What I’m missing here and what needs to be corrected?

> ```
> <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
>            maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
>     <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
>     <SSLHostConfig>
>         <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/ssl/crt2022/ssl.key"
>                      certificateFile="conf/ssl/crt2022/ServerCertificate.crt"
>                      certificateChainFile="conf/ssl/crt2022/ChainBundle2.crt"
>                      type="RSA" />
>     </SSLHostConfig>
> </Connector>
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse WTP: How do I enable SSL on Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951890/eclipse-wtp-how-do-i-enable-ssl-on-tomcat)

Comment: No, this answer not working for me. Am not using Eclipse to execute the service. I'm running tomcat from Linux VM

Comment: There are a bunch of other related questions - maybe you can find an existing answer there as this seems to be more of a common problem that others are likely to have encountered before.

Comment: Creating an SSL connector should _enable_ HTTPS (SSL/TLS) connections, but it does _not prevent_ HTTP (insecure) ones. Are (all!) your clients trying to connect with HTTPS to port 8443? (PS: the word for non-root CAs is 'intermediate'. They are also called 'chain' CAs/certs, which is easier to type :-)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - yes, its connecting to the PORT 8443.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - after adding the below conf, tomcat not starting

"    <Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           SSLCertificateFile="/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.29/conf/ssl/ServerCertificate.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.29/conf/ssl/serverkey.key"
           SSLCertificateChainFile="/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.29/conf/ssl/ChainBundle2.crt"
           SSLVerifyClient="optional" SSLProtocol="TLS"/>"

Comment: When Tomcat doesn't start.... what *does* it do? Check the logs for error messages and update your question with anything relevant.